# Google Chrome and all Electron apps no longer display on screen (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, google-chrome, amdgpu, mesa

After a recent update and restart Google Chrome and ALL of my Electron based apps no longer appear on the screen.

They start okay and I can see them running in the system monitor and htop. I can also see the application window by right clicking the dock icon and clicking all windows, I can see a thumbnail of the running application but there is simply no output whatsoever on the desktop. All other native applications and steam games run okay.

Running **Chrome** from the CLI:

```
mesa: for the --simplifycfg-sink-common option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --global-isel-abort option: may only occur zero or one times!
[10408:10408:0114/140820.186528:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(378)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
mesa: for the --amdgpu-atomic-optimizations option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --structurizecfg-skip-uniform-regions option: may only occur zero or one times!
[10365:10390:0114/140823.188562:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[10365:10390:0114/140823.188583:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[10409:10421:0114/140842.375697:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

**Spotify**:

```
(spotify:10749): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:20.470: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1428:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(spotify:10749): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:20.473: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3318:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(spotify:10749): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:20.474: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3780:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
```

**Simplenote**:

```
(simplenote:10934): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:56.781: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1428:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(simplenote:10934): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:56.784: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3318:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(simplenote:10934): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:56.785: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3780:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
```

I've tried removing Google Chrome completely with apt purge and deleted all the configs and reinstall but it's still the same.

Is there something else I should be trying?

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you use the command `spotify --no-zygote`
But the error message will continue in the terminal, in this question I don't know why.